# Solving ODE without explicit expression for the system

Tags: differential-equations

I have a system of differential equations, where
$$ \mathbf{y}'(x)=\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{y})$$
but I don't have an explicit expression for $f$, in fact I have to solve a linear system of equations to obtain $\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{y})$ for any $\mathbf{y}(x)$. I know I can't do this with NDSolve which just requires a simple expression for the ODE system. I want a method, much like the Scipy ODE solver, that gets $\mathbf{y}'(x)$ by calling a Mathematica function (that I have defined) that gives $\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{y})$. Is there such a thing?

Comment: I don't see why NDSolve couldn't do this. It would be helpful if you provided a simple example of what you're trying to do.

Comment: You might want to read up on using `_?NumericQ` to define your f(y).  Try [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/26037#26037) for starters.  But yeah, a simple, concrete example would help spur answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the OP didn't provide an example, here is a made up function `f`:

```
A = RandomReal[1, {4,4}];
f[y:{__?NumericQ}] := LinearSolve[A, y]
```

Here's an ODE that uses `f`:

```
sol = NDSolve[{y'[x] == f[y[x]], y[0] == {1,2,3,4}}, y, {x,0,1}];
sol //OutputForm
```

> {{y -> InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 1.}}, <>]}}

Finally, here is the value at $x=1$:

```
y[1] /. First @ sol
```

> {-13.846, 3.39417, 17.1691, -3.79776}

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. This is exactly the solution I was looking for. I'm surprised this isn't mentioned in the documentation for NDSolve